# Counting rows with NaN

Tags: python

I have the following DataFrame:

```
dur  wage1  wage2  wage3  cola  hours     pension  stby_pay  shift_diff
6   3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
8   1.0    2.8    NaN    NaN  none   38.0  empl_contr       2.0         3.0
9   1.0    5.7    NaN    NaN  none   40.0  empl_contr       NaN         4.0
13  1.0    5.7    NaN    NaN  none   40.0  empl_contr       NaN         4.0
17  3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
31  1.0    5.7    NaN    NaN  none   40.0  empl_contr       NaN         4.0
43  2.0    2.5    3.0    NaN   NaN   40.0        none       NaN         NaN
44  1.0    2.8    NaN    NaN  none   38.0  empl_contr       2.0         3.0
47  3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
```

What I have to do is count the rows that are exactly the same, including the NaN values.

The problem is the following, I use groupby, but it is a function that ignores the NaN values, that is, it does not have them in mind when doing the counting, that is the reason why I am not returning a correct output counting the number of exact repetitions between those rows.

My code is the following one:

```
def detect_duplicates(data):
    x = DataFrame(columns=data.columns.tolist() + ["num_reps"])

    aux = data[data.duplicated(keep=False)]
    x = data[data.duplicated(keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
    #This line should count my repeated rows
    s = aux.groupby(data.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).transform('size')


    return x
```

If I print "x" var, I get this result, it shows all the repeated rows:

```
dur  wage1  wage2  wage3  cola  hours     pension  stby_pay  shift_diff
6   3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
8   1.0    2.8    NaN    NaN  none   38.0  empl_contr       2.0         3.0
9   1.0    5.7    NaN    NaN  none   40.0  empl_contr       NaN         4.0
13  1.0    5.7    NaN    NaN  none   40.0  empl_contr       NaN         4.0
17  3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
31  1.0    5.7    NaN    NaN  none   40.0  empl_contr       NaN         4.0
43  2.0    2.5    3.0    NaN   NaN   40.0        none       NaN         NaN
44  1.0    2.8    NaN    NaN  none   38.0  empl_contr       2.0         3.0
47  3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
51  3.0    2.0    3.0    NaN   tcf    NaN  empl_contr       NaN         NaN
53  2.0    2.5    3.0    NaN   NaN   40.0        none       NaN         NaN
```

Now I have to count those rows from my x result that are exactly the same.

This should be my correct output:

```
 dur    wage1   wage2   wage3   cola    hours   pension stby_pay    shift_diff  num_reps
6   3.0 2.0 3.0 NaN tcf NaN empl_contr  NaN NaN                4
8   1.0 2.8 NaN NaN none    38.0    empl_contr  2.0 3.0        2
9   1.0 5.7 NaN NaN none    40.0    empl_contr  NaN 4.0        3
43  2.0 2.5 3.0 NaN NaN 40.0    none    NaN NaN                2
```

Here is my problem and it's that groupby ignores NaN values, and that's why other similar posts about this problem can't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe's name is df, you can count the number of duplicates using just one line of code:

```
sum(df.duplicated(keep = False))
```

If you want to drop duplicate rows, use the drop_duplicates method. [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Example:

```
#data.csv
col1,col2,col3
a,3,NaN #duplicate
b,9,4   #duplicate
c,12,5
a,3,NaN #duplicate
b,9,4   #duplicate
d,19,20
a,3,NaN #duplicate - 5 duplicate rows
```

Importing data.csv and dropping duplicate rows (by default the first instance of a duplicated row is kept)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df.drop_duplicates())
#Output
   c1   c2   c3
0   a   3   NaN
1   b   9   4.0
2   c   12  5.0
5   d   19  20.0
```

To count the number of duplicates rows, use the dataframe's duplicated method. Set "keep" to False ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)). As mentioned above, you can simply do this using `sum(df.duplicated(keep = False))`. Here's a messier way to do it that demonstrates what the "duplicated" method does:

```
duplicate_rows = df.duplicated(keep = False)
print(duplicate_rows)

#count the number of duplicates (i.e. count the number of 'True' values in 
#the duplicate_rows boolean series.

number_of_duplicates = sum(duplicate_rows)

print("Number of duplicate rows:")

print(number_of_duplicates)

#Output

#The duplicate_rows pandas series from df.duplicated(keep = False)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool

#The number of rows from sum(df.duplicated(keep = False))
Number of duplicate rows:
5
```

Comment: Yeah, is what I'm doing, but I have also to count the number of repeated rows, and save it for example in a column called c4 for example.

Comment: @fiticida Maybe something like `df['c4'] = len(df) - len(df.drop_duplicates())`?

Comment: I edited my answer and added an explanation on how to count the number of duplicate rows.

Comment: 0x543: Your method would work if you tweaked it slightly. `df['c4'] = len(df) - len(df.drop_duplicates(keep = False))`


Example: Row 1 is duplicated 3 times (so we have 4 identical rows). df has 10 rows. drop_duplicates() will keep the first row, and drop the 3 duplicates. df.drop_duplicates() will reQturn a dataframe with 7 rows. len(df) - len(df.drop_duplicates()) will be equal to 10 - 7 = 3.

If, instead, we have 4 rows that each have 1 duplicate. Then df.drop_duplicates() will drop 4 rows.  So len(df.drop_duplicates()) will be 4. len(df) - len(df.drop_duplicates()) will be 10-4 = 6.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.

The problem as I said was groupby that doesn't not accept Nan Values.

So what I have done to solve it, is to change all Nan Values with fillna(0) function so it changes all NaN to 0 and now I can do the comparation properly.

Here is my new function working properly:

```
def detect_duplicates(data):
    x = DataFrame(columns=data.columns.tolist() + ["num_reps"])

    aux = data[data.duplicated(keep=False)]
    x = data[data.duplicated(keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
    s =  aux.fillna(0).groupby(data.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
    x['num_reps'] = s['count'].tolist()[::-1]

    return x
```

Comment: Oh I see now what you were trying to do. Nice job.